# Imported datatype clashes with locally defined one, even when renamed

Tags: module, agda

With the following Agda code, I get an error on the definition of `B` in `A₂`:

```
module Whatever where

module A₁ where
  data B : Set where

module A₂ where
  open A₁ renaming (B to B₁)
  data B : Set where
```

The error message is:

```
Duplicate definition of module B. Previous definition of datatype
module B at /home/cactus/prog/agda/modules.agda:4,8-9
when scope checking the declaration
  data B where
```

But I am renaming `B` to `B₁` on the import, so why does it still clash? And is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that data types define a module and a name. You need to rename the module, too. This works:

```
module Cactus where

module A₁ where
  data B : Set where

module A₂ where
  open A₁ renaming (B to B₁; module B to B₁)
  data B : Set where
```

This allows you to refer to constructors in a module-ish way, so if you have a conflict between `Level.suc` and your `ℕ` one, you can just write `ℕ.suc` and have it work without having to go through renaming shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an Agda bug to me. You can report the bug in http://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/list.

Comment: Filed as http://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=838; once someone acknowledges it there as a bug, I'll accept this answer.